# Exporting pdf with jspdf-html2canvas css not wroking in iphone device. working fine in android device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

import html2df from "jspdf-html2canvas"
printBooking() = () => {

```
 var pdfData = document.getElementById("printArea");
 html2df(pdfData,{
```

jsPDF:{
unit:"px",
format:'a4',
},

```
imageType:'image/jpeg',
output:'file.pdf',
success:function(pdf){
if(/webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){


window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'))
}
else{
 pdf.save(this.output)
}
}
});
}
```

}

Comment: Please anyone can help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.